# Estimating the number of colors in a bucket

Tags: pr.probability

> This question was previously posted to Math Stack Exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193128/estimating-the-number-of-colors-in-a-bucket).

Suppose we have a bucket containing a large (but known) number of balls. Each of the balls has a color. We don't know how many colors there are, but given a ball of one color, we have an oracle which can tell us how many of the other balls also have that color. If we are allowed to repeatedly reach in, pick a ball, observe its color, and return it, how should  we estimate the number of colors in the bucket?

More precisely, suppose we are given $N$ samples $\{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_N\}$ from a uniform distribution on some finite set $S$. We know $|S|$, and are given, as black boxes,

- an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S$, so that for any $s_i$ and $s_j$, we can check if $s_i \sim s_j$. (Take $\sim$ to be drawn from a uniform distribution over all equivalence relations on $S$.)
- a function $f: S \to \mathbb{N}$ where $f(s)$ computes the cardinality of the equivalence class of $s$ under $\sim$.

Using these tools, how can we estimate the number of equivalence classes in $S / \sim$?

Comment: Not well if many of the equivalence classes are singletons.  If you have a nontrivial guarantee on the size of the smallest possible equivalence class, then you may get more confident estimates of the number of classes from a small sample using straightforward calculations.

Comment: To consider the difficulties, imagine a version where all the equivalence classes have 2 or 3 (or even 1 or 2) members, and consider how little information such a sample will yield.